# Safari browser is not caching images, site built with Angular

Tags: angular, image, google-chrome, safari, browser-cache

I have a site built with Angular 6. We have a problem with caching images on the safari browser.

Images are continuously downloaded on safari browser, even the image URL is same.
Chrome works well without downloading the same images, but having an issue just with the Safari browser.

Could you please share your experience with this kind of problem?

Comment: How do you detect that image is not cached? Are you sure you have "disable cache" option turned off? Are you talking about simple browser caching or some service worker or manifest based caching strategies?

Comment: Could you also share a link to the site / repository or add some screenshots of the network tab in dev tools

Comment: Can you please paste screenshot of network tab of your browser

Comment: What do you mean with "even the image URL is the same"? Also: Are you running Chrome and Safari on the same machine or from different network sectors?

Answer (score 0):

Given the sparse information, I can give the following hints:

1. If you are packing (e.g. with [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)) **you could configure which items are cached**, maybe even whether they are cached for which browser. So you might want to dive into the packaging step which e.g. generates a `bundle.js`. This happened for me on a project I took over.
2. If it is only happening with a single browser (instance), it might be worth checking the preferences of the given browser. **Caching might be disabled directly or indirectly.** Assuming you did not disable the cache of your browser, there might be some traffic shaping tools active on the way to your machine on which runs Safari, if the Chrome browser was tested from a different machine.
3. Last but not least, it might be also a **network time-out issue**. I know Chrome is relatively reliable when it has to wait for long (e.g. for a large image), back in the days when I used Safari, it was rather impatient, i.e. it always looked as the time-out was quicker. I am not though, whether that was the effect of the browser, or rather of the overall configuration.